# Get INT value between 2 matching chars

Tags: c#

I have a string that I need to separate the product ID from, is this format

```
shop:?id:556:token:bmgwcGJxZEpnK2RqemhaKzdBYWZjbTVZN0xaOXh5L3pmdDBFZjQrWVVES1pmYVBXVVB6SlFhejBsNndnaHNsUA==
```

I need to get 556 out of there, and in the case of say 2658 etc also possible.

First index ":" I think
`str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);`

But then I dont know how to just break after the match, regex better? any help apprecaited

**EDIT**

These do the exact same thing, seperating the first numbers out

LINQ:

```
var test = new string(str.Substring(str.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray())).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Reggex:

```
var test = Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value;
```

So bears the question, which is better approach?

Comment: _Regex_ is your friend

Comment: *which is better approach?* is the format of the string fixed? What range of values does id have?

Comment: The LINQ approach is fairly awful, I'd say

Comment: fixed string, always in this format, but last string after token: changes dynamically as well as the ID as noted after the first : in the string - IDs will be from 5 - 27000 - I wanna make sure I am capturing all of those numbers

Comment: Added a succinct substringing version to my answer that uses the c#9 ranges syntax. Loads of ways to skin the cat, I'd say pick the one that appeals most to your notions of code readability/glanceability, but I'd definitely avoid the linq route..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string format is fixed, use the Split function

```
string str = "shop:?id:556:token:bmgwcGJxZEpnK2RqemhaKzdBYWZjbTVZN0xaOXh5L3pmdDBFZjQrWVVES1pmYVBXVVB6SlFhejBsNndnaHNsUA==";
int id = Convert.ToInt32(str.Split(':')[2]);
Console.WriteLine(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use Regex:

```
var id = Regex.Match(input, @"\?id:(?<x>\d+)").Groups["x"].Value
```

Decoded, that Regex means "literally match `?id:` then start a capturing group called x and capture one or more digits into it"

The returned Match will have a Groups property that we index by x and retrieve the value

If you want it as an int you can int.Parse the result-you won't need a TryParse because the Regex will have only matched digits

---

If the format of the string is fixed then this would work:

```
input[9..input.IndexOf(':',10)];
```

And it would be more performant than Regex or Split

If you wanted a substring that works with a format change, perhaps:

```
var x = input.IndexOf("?id:") + 4;
var id = input[x..input.IndexOf(':',x+1)];
```

Comment: How is that any different than the short and sweet Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value ?

Comment: It's not, particularly, it's just more specific - if the string format ever changed and id moved then it would still find it. I also tend to use named capturing groups (with better names than x) for clarity of subsequent code, particularly when the Rex match picks up more than one capture.

Comment: ..but these are mainly habits and in part driven by on SO not knowing the whole story or context behind a question and the variables involved

Comment: that is actually very useful in case of format change. See, this string is actually a custom url that launches the app and passes params to form etc

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if the order of items changes.

```
string original = "shop:?id:556:token:bmgwcGJxZEpnK2RqemhaKzdBYWZjbTVZN0xaOXh5L3pmdDBFZjQrWVVES1pmYVBXVVB6SlFhejBsNndnaHNsUA==";
string startWithId = original.Substring(original.IndexOf("id:") + 3);
string onlyId = startWithId.Split(':')[0];
Console.WriteLine(onlyId);
```

Comment: It's not necessary to comment on your own answer, just _edit it_